# Can't execute MSTest through powershell remote session

Tags: powershell, mstest

I'm unable to execute MSTest on a remote machine from within a powershell remote session, but it works perfectly if I'm logged into that remote machine and run it locally. My guess is that this indicates a permissions issue of some sort, but I have been unable to determine the problem. Here's the 2-liner I use to execute the tests successfully (locally) on the target machine:

```
PS> $params = @("/testcontainer:MyTests.dll", "/nologo", "/detail:stdout")
PS> & "MSTest" $params
```

I'm getting the following error when I attempt this through a PSRemote session:

```
Run has the following issue(s):
Test host process exited unexpectedly.
Failed to queue test run 'username@machinename 2015-08-10 03:30:18': Unable to start the agent process.
```

Any ideas what might be going on here? I'm using the same credentials to create the PSSession as I use when logging into the target machine with Remote Desktop, but apparently that's no good. Is it possible that because the tests use Selenium ChromeDriver there's some issue with starting a GUI program remotely?

Comment: Have you tried `vstest.console.exe`?  That is the preferred executable in VS2012 and above.  It could be that the old mstest.exe has problems and they are addressed by the new exe.

Comment: @JohnKoerner good point. need to try https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj155796(v=vs.110).aspx